# With a monthly subscription chatgpt api give 429 error

Tags: python, openai-api, chatgpt-api

I'm trying to use Openai API, I bought a monthly subscription, my payment method is Paypal.
I try with an official example in Python:

```
 from openai import OpenAI
 client = OpenAI(
    api_key = 'my_key'  
 )

 response = client.completions.create(
    model="gpt-3.5-turbo-instruct",
    prompt="Write a tagline for an ice cream shop."
 )
```

but when I launch my Python script I receive this error:

```
 raise self._make_status_error_from_response(err.response) from None
 openai.RateLimitError: Error code: 429 - {'error': {'message': 'You exceeded your current 
 quota, please check your plan and billing details.', 'type': 'insufficient_quota', 'param': 
 None, 'code': 'insufficient_quota'}}
```

This is the situation of my usage account:

[Usage account]https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjFnl.png

I have some difficult to understand what it means..I read similar questions but they doesn't solve my problem.
Some hint or help?

Comment: What do you find difficult to understand about *You exceeded your current 
 quota, please check your plan and billing details*?